# Spring Data MongoDB query performance is slower with respect to MongoDB Compass

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I'm fetching records of around 1200 records, if I query it from Mongo Compass, it uses the Compound Index which I created, and from **20ms(without indexing) to 0ms** the performance shows, but If I use the same query in my Spring Boot Java project using Document class and using the  below query, it takes up to **2 secs** to fetch the same record.

To create indexes I used to db.collectionName.createIndex()

Below is the Java Spring Data Query

```
@Query(value="{country:?0, age: ?1}",fields="{'name':1,'state':1}")
public List<Object> getcountrySpecificName(String country, String name);
```

Comment: I suspect that the problem here is that Spring doesn't know that your indexes exist. Give this a read, it might help: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-mongodb-index-annotations-converter#indexes